# Creating custom UITableView for reuse

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that I would like to reuse in different View Controllers.

I would like to know who should be the `delegate`/`datasource` if the `tableView` is of a custom class.

I would also like to know to where to point the `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets of the `tableView`,

And whether or not the subclassing of `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` should be done in the custom UITableView class or in the controller controlling it.

Comment: You probably don’t need to subclass `UITableView` at all. Are those three methods in your code snippet the only ones you’re overriding?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct way to implement what you want to do. What you "reuse" is your data model objects that populate the table views, no the UITableView itself. You don't subclass the data source and delegates. You make a class extension or category (if Objective-C) on a custom class and conform that class to the protocols.